# My data table has some html elements in it, how to databind as html

Tags: html, asp.net, gridview

One of my columns in my data table contains a value like the following:

```
<strong>Hello World</strong>
```

How do I databind that to my GridView so it will show bold and not the words strong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems using the `BoundField` will put out the Entity characters instead of the actual characters (e.g. `&lt;` instead of `<`). I've tested this and it seems to work if you just `Eval` your column in a `TemplateColumn` like so:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Link">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# Eval("MyField") %>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```